# split one line into multiple line using number of bytes

Tags: unix

I want to split single line into multiple line of 8 bytes each. And I am using the `fold` command and since this file contains the special characters the `fold` command does  not work and it breaks in the middle of multibyte character.

#### File Content

```
あいbbえおかcc髙①こさし㈱㈱ちつて髙aabbc
```

#### Command Used

```
fold -b8 dummy_file.dat
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, could you explain why you want to fold it by 8 bytes lines?
Can we do it via 8 characters? The problem here is that your text contains 2 bytes characters that will be broken if we split them on 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks Allan for your reply. Actually it is a customer business requirement, we can't do it by 8 characters. And yes there are couple of ways to fold it by characters but didn't found any option for bytes.

Comment: And what does the business do when there are multiple-bytes char?
Your line can just be 8 bytes lengths if it contains only ASCII char.
If all the chars are coded on 2 bytes then you will have 4 characters on your line.
However imagine a situation if you have `abcd123え` how do you want to split it?
there are 8 characters but they are coded on 9 bytes. If you cut it after 8 bytes you will alter the content. If you accept that the first line is only 7 bytes and the 2 nd lines 2 bytes then that is fine, however you can not just cut it on exactly 8 bytes...

Comment: Could you review the exact requirements with your customer? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer!

Comment: Hi Allan, As per business, the file that is received from source system will be such that one line will be always be 8 bytes which be combination of single & multi-byte. But the total will be always 8 byte of 1 row. if there is imore than 8 bytes then it is issue with the data which customer need to correct. Thanks for sharing the python code. Would it possible for you to use the character set as 'Shift_JIS' instead of 'utf-8'.? Again thanks for your helping on this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your text contains multi-bytes characters that will be broken by the `fold` command if we split them on 2 lines.

```
echo "あいbbえおかcc髙①こさし㈱㈱ちつて髙aabbc" | fold -b8 
あいbb
えお��
�cc髙��
�こさ�
��㈱㈱
ちつ��
�髙aabb
c
```

If you want to have 8 characters per line you can use the following `sed` command:

```
echo "あいbbえおかcc髙①こさし㈱㈱ちつて髙aabbc" | sed 's/.\{8\}/&\n/g'
あいbbえおかc
c髙①こさし㈱㈱
ちつて髙aabb
c
```

that add a breakline after each occurrence of `8` characters.

If you do not want to display 8 characters but want to constraint each line to be at most 8 bytes without breaking the text content then you can use the python script:

```
import sys

def utf8len(s):
  return len(s.encode('utf-8'))

entry = unicode(sys.stdin.read(),'utf-8')

tmp = ''
for c in entry:
  if utf8len(tmp)+utf8len(c) > 8:
    print tmp
    tmp = c
  elif utf8len(tmp)+utf8len(c) == 8:
    print tmp,c
    tmp = ''
  else:
    tmp += c

if tmp:
  print tmp
```

**output:**

```
echo -n "あいbbえおかcc髙①こさし㈱㈱ちつて髙aabbc" | python max8bytes.py 
あいb b
えお
かcc 髙
①こ
さし
㈱㈱
ちつ
て髙a a
bbc
```

**Explanations:**

You define a function that will count how many bytes you have per char.
You read char by char `stdin` and you avoid to have more than `8` bytes on the same line. If you do not want to have less than you can add some spaces char at the end of each line.